# excel vba if statement with OR and AND scenario

Tags: vba, excel

I  have an email messaging system that chooses a different language template based on the nationality of the current record. I need to make the language selection dynamic though, since the end user does not always want to send the message in the entry's national language, which means that for example if the record state a nationality of "IT" (Italy), I want to check if the languages template is set as "Active" before proceeding, respectively default to EN (English) in case the template is "Inactive".

```
'check for nationality and select letter template accordingly
    ' Use german for DE, AT and CH nationalities
    If nationality = "DE" Or nationality = "AT" Or nationality = "CH" Then
        Set rng = Sheets("PostStayEmail_DE").Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_DE")
            'do something
        End With`

    'Use italian for IT nationalities
        ElseIf nationality = "IT" Then
        Set rng = Sheets("PostStayEmail_IT").Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_IT")
              'do something

        End With
```

Now, what I need for the if statement would be something like this

```
if (nationality = "DE" or nationality = "AT" or nationality = "CH") _
                          AND (Range("B5") = "Active") then
    'do something

Elseif ... 'check other languages
```

How can I combine those OR statements for multiple languages but also add an AND statement to check if the template is active?

Comment: whats the problem you are facing now

Comment: Is it the range B5 on each of the language template sheets which you need to check?  How many different templates do you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
If ((nationality = "DE" Or nationality = "AT" Or nationality = "CH") And Range("B5").Value = "Active") Then
    Set Rng = Sheets("PostStayEmail_DE").Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_DE")
        'do something
    End With
ElseIf ((nationality = "IT") And Range("B5").Value = "Active") Then
    Set Rng =   Sheets("PostStayEmail_IT").Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_IT")
        'do something
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) may help tidy up the multiple matches.

```
if lcase(Range("B5").Value) = "active" then
    select case ucase(nationality)
        case "DT", "AT", "CH"
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_DE")
                Set rng = .Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                'do something
            End With
        case "IT"
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PostStayEmail_IT")
                Set rng = .Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                'do something
            End With
        case else
            'do thing if no matches
    end select
else
    'do stuff when B5 is not 'Active'
end if
```

Depending upon the repetition of the code for the various combinations of ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 two letter country codes, you may simply wish to record the worksheet name and leave all further processing in a single block below the Select Case.

Comment: kudos for that as it cleanly addresses possible cases. very much like that solution as I am doing the above over and again for each message template.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (nationality = "DE" OR nationality = "AT" OR nationality = "CH") _
                          AND Range("B5") = "Active" then

'do something

End If
```

This should work